# Why isn't my machine.config HttpModule running in my web app?

Tags: .net, configuration, iis-7.5, httpmodule, windows-server-2008-r2

I wrote a `HttpModule` in .NET 3.5, 32 bit Win 2003, IIS 6 that worked great. Its assemblies were in the GAC and the config was in the `machine.config`. Everything has been great for years.

I just brought it all over to a new .NET 2-4, 64 bit Win 2008 R2, IIS 7.5 machine and put the same, old configuration in the `machine.config`. Unfortunately, the module isn't listed as those that are running on the site. When I put the configuration directly into a site's `web.config`, then it runs as expected. **Why isn't my app inheriting the HttpModule from the `machine.config`?**

*This config does nothing in the machine.config, but works as expected in the web.config.*

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="MyModule" type="MyModule, MyAssmebly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdefghijklmno" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I put the config in every possible machine.config file to no avail:

- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`

## UPDATE

Other elements of the configuration are inherited to the web.config: `system.web\compilation` and `system.serviceModel\bindings` to name a couple. The module uses WCF that is configured in `machine.config`. It appears to just be the `HttpModule` that isnt being inherited. No, there is no `<clear/>` anywhere.

Comment: What is the mode of the application pool the site is sitting in?

Comment: Did you try to put it in the global `web.config`, instead of the `machine.config`?

Comment: Did you rebooted the server??? Normally it is not needed but if it is a test server worth retrying.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment It is in integrated mode.

Comment: @Aliostad I've rebooted IIS but not the whole machine.

Comment: @Oded Yes, I tried previously and I just tried again, rebooting IIS after the attempt. No luck.

Comment: @Jeff This is a long shot (it seems you're not getting errors, it's just not working), but since the configs are shared, can you try disabling validation by adding the following above your `<modules>`: `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />`

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment No luck with that :(

Comment: @Jeff With the config files being shared, there _might_ have been a conflicting issue with validating the structure if _anything_ was using classic mode with others in integrated (producing errors, usually visible, hence my "long shot") - this essentially tells IIS that you know what is in the config _and_ that is it correct / required, skipping any distinct errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `machine.config` is not responsible for defining the `system.webServer` section. In fact, it defines the section as

```
<section name="system.webServer" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

Note the type: `System.Configuration.IgnoreSection`.

The `system.webServer` section is defined in

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config
```

Directly after the `system.webserver` section, there is

```
<location path="" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>

    <modules>
        <!-- add the module here -->
        <add name="MyModule" type="MyNamespace.MyModule, MyAssmebly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdefhijklmnop"/>

    </modules>

    </system.webServer>

</location>
```